# How to fix range error where number of rows in the don't match number of rows in the range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following script which matches the cell values in `column P`, `array x[10]` and `column AA`, `array x[21`], of the *BLOCK ORDERS* sheet with the prices from either the *QUOTATIONS* sheet or *Products* sheet and puts the price values in either columns `AC` or `AC` of the *BLOCK ORDERS* sheet. If the script runs perfect when there is a value in each row of the range of column `P` and also in each row of column `AA`. When there is a blank cell in either column `P` or in column `AA` it gives the ***error***:

```
The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 3.
updateQuotationPrice    @ Code.gs:56
```

I have tried changing the range but unable to get the solution:

```
ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 26, lr1 -1 , 1).setValues(output);
```

Here's [the link for the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UMO4Fxaz1hqjnUx9rPpVM0Z03B7uyfynvV5enJz8ZmU/edit?usp=sharing) . Thank you for any assistance.

```
 function updateQuotationPrice() { 
  
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1UMO4Fxaz1hqjnUx9rPpVM0Z03B7uyfynvV5enJz8ZmU"); //BLOCK ORDERS Update
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10tb0zE_8i849T-hL6mU-Pw_4V-aMzNZJGNOFYG1F3qk"); //Quotation
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jbG_PLWU_eXfQTkwUn1krtYfzniw7HwnwnunhohzL60"); //PRODUCTS
  var svar = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jbG_PLWU_eXfQTkwUn1krtYfzniw7HwnwnunhohzL60');
  var shvar = svar.getSheetByName("VARIABLES");
  // get part load variable and jobs
  const ster13N = shvar.getRange(3,18,1,1).getValue();
  const euro13N = shvar.getRange(3,19,1,1).getValue();


 //Extract data from User Update
  var lr1 = ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getLastRow();
  var data1 = ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 6, lr1, 61).getValues();
  //var price1 = ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 26, lr1, 1).getValues();
  
//var jobsRange = jobSheet.getRange("O2:BO" + jobSheet.getLastRow())
 // var jobs = jobsRange.getValues()
  //Extract data from Quotation Spreadsheet
  var sheetNames2 = [];
  ss2.getSheets().forEach(x => sheetNames2.push(x.getName()));

  //Process data 1
  var output = [];
  data1.forEach((x,i) => {
    var zoneSurcharge = x[58];
    
    if (sheetNames2.includes(x[0]) && ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10])).length > 0 ) { // added new condition here
      if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[10] != "") {
        output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][3]+zoneSurcharge]);
      }
      else if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[10] != "") {
        output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][2]+zoneSurcharge]);
      }
    }
    else  
      if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[12] == "13 Newton" && x[10] != "" ) {surcharges = zoneSurcharge + euro13N
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][3]+surcharges]) ;
      }
      else 
      if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[12] == "13 Newton" && x[10] != "") {surcharges = zoneSurcharge + ster13N
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][2]+surcharges]); 
      }
    else 
      if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[12] == "10 Newton" && x[10] != "") {
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][3]+zoneSurcharge]);
      }
      else if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[12] == "10 Newton" && x[10] != "") {
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[10]))[0][2]+zoneSurcharge]); 
      } 
    
  });
  console.log(output);
 //Output 
  ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 26, lr1 -1 , 1).setValues(output); 

  //Process data 2
  var output = [];
  data1.forEach(x => {
    var zoneSurcharge = x[58];
    
    if (sheetNames2.includes(x[0]) && ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[21])).length > 0) { // added new condition here
      if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[21] !="") {
        output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[21]))[0][3]+zoneSurcharge]);
      }
      else if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[21] !="") {
        output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[21]))[0][2]+zoneSurcharge]);
      }
    }
    else  
      if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[12] == "13 Newton" && x[21] !="") {surcharges = zoneSurcharge + euro13N
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[21]))[0][3]+surcharges]) ;
      }
      else 
      if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[12] == "13 Newton" && x[21] !="") {surcharges = zoneSurcharge + ster13N
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[21]))[0][2]+surcharges]); 
      }
    else 
      if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[12] == "10 Newton" && x[21] !="") {
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[21]))[0][3]+zoneSurcharge]);
      }
      else if (x[9] == "STERLING" && x[12] == "10 Newton" && x[21] !="") {
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("PRODUCTS").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[21]))[0][2]+zoneSurcharge]); 
      } 
  });
  
 //Output 
  ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 29, lr1 - 1, 1).setValues(output);

 }
```

Comment: Try it this way: `ss1.getSheetByName("BLOCK ORDERS").getRange(2, 29, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining the last row in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a sample sheet of other spreadsheets so that we can easily replicate the error that you are experiencing? It poses a challenge to visualise the other sheets based only on the script you have provided.

Comment: @Cooper, yes this fixes the range error I was having, thankyou. Can you please advise how the range can the changed so the output is in the same row as the corresponding cell in column P rather than putting the output starting at row 2?

Comment: I don't understand your last question

Comment: @Cooper,the getRange is getRange(2, 26, output.length, output[0].length) which puts the output value in row 2 and row 3 of column 26. The output values are set from column 16, indice x[10] which values are in row 3 and row 4. I require the output values in column 26 to be and row 3 and row 4 also. I hope you can follow this

Comment: It starts write output at row 2 not row 3.  I don't care where the output was gathered from .  That's independant of the write.

Comment: If you need to change the contents of the output go ahead and do it.  You initial question was about the setValues() statement.

Comment: @Cooper, Ok understood. Any suggestions as how to I might modify so the output depends on where it was gathered from?

Comment: The output always depends upon where it was gathered.  I don't understand your question.